# Graphic in LATEX

Tags: math-mode, diagrams

Is it possible to do this, or do anybody know how to do it? thanks

[image]

I've been trying and having so many time to learn. I already learned a bit with `circuitikz` but still don't know how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to the site! :) Yes it's definitely possible. In all likelihood somebody will come along to help you (not me, I'm afraid, I can't TikZ) at some point. However, this site works best as a Q & A site for specific issues. Draw this for me questions are usually answered, but many people don't like them, because it's asking quite a lot of the community. However, other people like playing with TikZ so ... The bottom line is, though, the more you give us the better. Anything, even just setting up the document and adding the text to it, so we don't have to type it out is better than nothing

Comment: Thank you so much! I know but I don't even know how to start. I had so many troubles with the electronic circuits but I had references in this website and several other places. But with this particular case I don't know to use the packages and so to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[gray!50](0,-0.2) rectangle +(2,0.4);
  \fill[gray!50](4,-0.2) rectangle +(2,0.4);
  \draw[thin,dashed](4,-1)--(4,1);
  \draw[thick](0,0) -- (8,0) node[anchor=west]{$\Omega$};
  \foreach \x/\txt in {0/{},2/25,4/100,6/400,8/{}} \draw[thick](\x,-0.2)--(\x,0.2) node[anchor=south,fill=white]{\txt};
  \draw(0,-0.3)node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt]{$\underbrace{\rule{4cm}{0pt}}_{\text{FONT DE I}}$};
  \draw(4,-0.3)node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt]{$\underbrace{\rule{4cm}{0pt}}_{\text{FONT DE V}}$};
  \draw(0,2mm+\baselineskip)node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt]{$\overbrace{\rule{2cm}{0pt}}^{P>0'25\text{ W}}$};
  \draw(4,2mm+\baselineskip)node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt]{$\overbrace{\rule{2cm}{0pt}}^{P>0'25\text{ W}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I really don't know how to thank you that took a while to do it! You made me so happy! I have to deliver a hard work and I've been stuck with this a while... :) :)